# PHP comparing strings

Tags: php, string, comparison

I have dates and timestamps stored for every item in my table, format of month/day/year respectively hour/minute. The topology looks like following:

```
---------------------------------
| Name  | ID | Date     | Time  |
---------------------------------
| Item1 | 1  | 04.15.13 | 09.17 |
---------------------------------
| Item2 | 2  | 04.17.13 | 12.58 |
---------------------------------
| Item3 | 3  | 04.18.13 | 22.43 |
---------------------------------
```

And so on. Using the PHP `date()` function I retrieve the current date and time of the server like this:

```
$date = date(m) . "." . date(d) . "." . date(y);
$time = date(H) . "." . date(i);
```

As am writing this, this would give me `$date = "04.18.13"` and `$time = "19.05"`.

If the current date and time is past the date and time stored for a specific item in my database, I want that item to be flagged as outdated/inactive when a user is browsing it. For instance:

- If it's April 16th 11.05, Item1 is inactive but Item2 and Item3 are still active.
- If it's April 17th 13.02, Item1 and Item2 are inactive but Item3 is still active.
- If it's April 18th 20.38, Item1 and Item2 are inactive but Item3 is still active.

I am completely lost if simple operators like `>, <, >=, <=` will work for this since I'm working with strings. How do I compare the dates and times retrieved from the database with the current date and time?

Summary: **How do I compare two strings, holding either a date or a time, with each other to figure out if an item is active or not?**

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? >=5.3?

Comment: First of all, you should use actual datetime fields in MySQL.  This will make your life much simpler.

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.3.3-7. What are datetime fields?

Comment: @SimonCarlson [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) objects from your strings. Like this:

```
# I assume that you've fetch date and time from mysql already
$time_from_db = DateTime::createFromFormat('m.D.y H.i',
             $mysql_record['date'] . ' ' . $mysql_record['time']);

$now = new DateTime();

# as of php 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using the <> == operators
if($now >= $time_from_db) {
    echo "it's in the past.";
}
```

Comment: `# DateTime objects can be compared using the <> == operators` ... as of PHP 5.2.2 But yeah, that's the way ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Do I have to create DateTime object in my database for this approach to work?

Comment: @Havelock Yes, really like `DateTime::createFromFormat`. :) Have integrated your comment.

Comment: @SimonCarlson No, this is just PHP code. As far as I see you currently have varchar columns for time and date. Isn't it?

Comment: @SimonCarlson, no - use the designated MySQL data types (see my comment to your question). Then you can easily load them into PHP DateTime objects

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, both date and time are varchar.

Answer (score 2):

If you combined your two fields into a single [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) field in MySQL this task would be trivial and able to be performed in the query itself.

Your table might look like this:

```
------------------------------------
| Name  | ID | active_until        |
------------------------------------
| Item1 | 1  | 2013-04-15 09:17:00 |
------------------------------------
| Item2 | 2  | 2013-04-17 12:58:00 |
------------------------------------
| Item3 | 3  | 2013-04-18 22:43:00 |
------------------------------------
```

And you could query it like this

```
Active Listings:
----------------
SELECT * FROM table WHERE active_until >= NOW()

Inactive Listings:
------------------
SELECT * FROM table WHERE active_until < NOW()

All listings with active/inactive indicator:
--------------------------------------------
SELECT
    *,
    (CASE WHEN active_until >= NOW() THEN 'active' ELSE 'inactive' END CASE) as `status`
FROM table
```

Comment: Have linked to mysql documentation. However, good answer and if the opener is free to design the database, maybe the best answer ... ;)